# JavaScript class TypeError X is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, typeerror, es6-class

this is something I couldn't resolve for a while. I am creating an ES6 class:

```
const https = require('https');

class LetsGrowHandler {
    constructor() {
    }

    connectLG() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            const post_options = 
                {
                    host: 'api.letsgrow.com',
                    path: '/Token',
                    method: 'POST'
                };
            const postData = require('querystring').stringify(
                {
                    username: '',
                    password: '',
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    signin: 'Sign in'
                });
            let data;
            const response = https.request(post_options, function (res) {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', () => {
                    resolve(data);
                });
            });
            response.on('error', (e) => {
                reject(e);
            });
            response.write(postData);
            response.end();
        });
    }
}

module.exports = LetsGrowHandler;
```

Then I want to test whether the function works properly with a simple unit test:

```
 describe('LetsGrowHandler', function () {
    describe('retrieve token', function () {
        it('connectLG should succeed', function (done) {
            // This was missing: const lgh = new LetsGrowHandler();            
            lgh.connectLG()
                .then(function (value) {
                    //console.log(value);
                    chai.assert(value.access_token !== null);
                    done();
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    chai.assert(1 === 3);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I get the result

```
        lgh .connectLG()
             ^

TypeError: lgh.connectLG is not a function
    at Suite.<anonymous> (D:\Code\ghdb\tests\LetsGrowHandler_test.js:7:15)
```

What does `Suite.<anonymous>` mean? Is that a pointer to the problem already?

What am I missing here?
Thank you,
Jens

Comment: The error message you posted says "legh", but the code is just "lgh". Which is it?

Comment: legh  is not defined is it ? same as upper comment: legh != lgh

Comment: OK that's not the problem. The problem is that you import the class but you do not create an *instance* of the class.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the class. `new lgh().connectLG()` though I don't know exactly why it's in a class.

Comment: How stupid of me :( instantiating the class, of course, solves the problem.

Comment: Btw, if that is your complete code of the `class`, you shouldn't be using a `class` at all. It doesn't have any properties (no state), only a single method, and you're not using an instance of it anywhere - so you should just `default export function connectLG() {…}` and be done with it.

Comment: The class is more complex than shown here.